# Wireless mouse no longer connects

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, mouse

I have a Logitech mouse (connected wirelessly through USB port, without Bluetooth).

It used to work fine on my Macbook until last week when I took an online exam where the proctor changed a few settings on my Macbook, for safety reasons. I don't remember everything that was changed to undo the changes. (I'm not sure it was the reason the mouse isn't working now, might be just a coincidence)

I'm going crazy here having to use the trackpad.

Any tips on what might be happening and possible solutions?

Comment: This would be a good time to raise the matter with your educational establishment, reminding them that any settings changed by any remote party in your own personal computer must be restored after the exam is finished.

Comment: Just me, but I'd have a *major* issue with anyone changing settings on a personal device.  If they require compliance, let them issue a device they control.  That said, boot into Recovery Mode and see if the mouse works there (it's an altogether  separate version of macOS from the one you boot).  If the mouse doesn't function there, you have a hardware issue.

Comment: We don't know where the OP resides on the planet, where stricter academic prohibitions may exist -- a condition of taking the exam may be to allow deliberate actions taken by the proctor on the examinee's computer. Can't take a look? Can't take the exam. Back to the question at hand. Daniel4321 - Is there a Logitech app in System Preferences, or an app in /Applications or Applications/Utilities? Perhaps running Logitech software may make the USB dongle visible again. Have you removed and reinserted the USB dongle from the laptop? Have you tried the dongle in another USB port?